# Eliminate Duplicate Code within RSpec Context

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

This is my rspec file. I have the `PosRequest.authorize_card(@payment_detail)` line 3 times.Is there a DRYer way to write this context?

```
context 'should get' do 
    it 'error message' do 
      PosRequest.authorize_card(@payment_detail)
      @payment_detail.errorMsg.should_not eql(:nil)
    end
    it 'bank message' do 
      PosRequest.authorize_card(@payment_detail)
      @payment_detail.cardMsg.should_not eql(:nil)
    end
    it 'claim message' do 
      PosRequest.authorize_card(@payment_detail)
      @payment_detail.bankMsg.should_not eql(:nil)
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
context 'should get' do 
  before {PosRequest.authorize_card(@payment_detail)}

  it 'sends error message' do 
    @payment_detail.errorMsg.should_not eql(:nil)
  end
  it 'sends bank message' do 
    @payment_detail.cardMsg.should_not eql(:nil)
  end
  it 'sends claim message' do 
    @payment_detail.bankMsg.should_not eql(:nil)
  end
end
```

I edited this to add verbs so that you have a clearer idea of what each spec is doing.

Answer (score 1):

Inside you `context` you can use the already suggested

```
before do
  do_something
end
```

that will run just once for all tests inside this context, or you can use

```
before :each do
  do_something
end
```

and this will run `do_something` once for each test inside this context, you can choose which fits better your needs.